# Video backward scrolling issues in avplayer seektotime

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In AVPlayer seektotime works fine on forward scrolling of the video, but in backward or reverse it skips the frame. but low quality videos are worked fine.Anyone have face this, if u know that pls tell me,

Thanks

Comment: What you are saying never happened to me in all qualities, please post your code, it may help detect the problem.

Comment: @muhammad if i export a video in low quality the backward works fine, but in AVAssetExportPreset640x480 quality video frames are skipped while backward..